# Disabling JComponents on a JPanel in for-loop: annoying delay

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a JFrame with a few JPanels. One is the boardPanel with a GridLayout of JButtons (4 by 4). The other is the controlPanel which has a FlowLayout which containt a JTextField and two JButtons.

I have two methods enableBoard() and disableBoard(). In those methods I setEnabled() each component in the boardPanel and controlPanel to true or false, via a for-loop. This all happens while a swing Timer is running. When I start the timer and thus start the enableBoard() (it was disabled via disableBoard) it kinda works, but often has a delay, so not all buttons get disabled at the same moment, I suspect it has something to do with the Timer because the delay seems to be happening in seconds... Here are the important methods:

```
public void disableBord() {
    Component[] boardcomps = boardPanel.getComponents();
    for(int i = 0; i < bordcomps.length; i++) {
        boardcomps[i].setEnabled(false);
    }

    Component[] checkComps = controlPanel.getComponents();
    for(int i = 0; i < checkComps.length; i++) {
        checkComps[i].setEnabled(false);
    }
}

public void enableBord() {
    Component[] boardcomps = boardPanel.getComponents();
    for(int i = 0; i < bordcomps.length; i++) {
        boardcomps[i].setEnabled(true);
    }

    Component[] checkComps = controlPanel.getComponents();
    for(int i = 0; i < checkComps.length; i++) {
        checkComps[i].setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

And the Timer that runs:

```
timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        int time = game.getSeconds()+4;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (time == game.getSeconds()+4) {
                lblFeedback.setText("3");
                lblTime.setText(game.secToMinSec(game.getSeconds()));
                time--;
            } else if (time == game.getSeconds()+3) {
                lblFeedback.setText("2");
                lbltime.setText(game.secToMinSec(game.getSeconds()));
                time--;
            } else if (time == game.getSeconds()+2) {
                lblFeedback.setText("1");
                lblTime.setText(game.secToMinSec(game.getSeconds()));
                time--;
            } else if (time == game.getSeconds()+1) {
                lblFeedback.setText("Start!");
                lblTime.setText(game.secToMinSec(time));
                time--;
                enableBord();
            } else if(time == 0) {
                lblTime.setText("0:00");
                lblFeedback.setText("Game finished!");
                disableBord();
                game.endeGame();
                timer.stop();
            } else if (time ==  game.getSeconds()) {
                lblTime.setText(game.secToMinSec(time));
                time--;
            } else {
                lblTime.setText(game.secToMinSec(time));
                time--;
            }
        }
    });
```

The delay looks like this:

[image: Delay when disabling JComponents]

Comment: no help possible without showing a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: @kleopatra Is this not enough information? I'm just looking for people who know what could be the problem, an SSCCE takes some time and I'm a bit short on time :/

Comment: The Timer fires every second. The code to enable/disable the components will execute in milliseconds so I double the Timer is the problem. It looks like your enable/disable code is executing on the EDT, which is correct so I don't see what the problem might be. We also have limited time and without all the facts are only guessing.

Comment: _people who know what could be the problem_ you are looking for super-naturals: while I think I might fit that profile, my crystal ball is cloudy today ;-) If you have no time to provide the information necessary to help you ... hire a consultant and pay her well ...

Comment: @kleopatra Too bad that exactly today it has to be cloudy :) Given the fact that I'm learning Java and making a school project the consultant option isn't really an option :) I meant that I thought maybe there would be someone who has had the same problem and solved it.

Answer (score 1):

A proper repaint(); after every setEnable() in the loop seemed to have solved my problem!